# XAP File being deleted on Internet Explorer Close

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight

I'm having an issue where whenever I open my silverlight app, the XAP file is re-downloaded. If I do not close internet explorer and just re open the app, the file is not downloaded again as it exists in the temporary files folder.

Under internet Options, I do not have the option set to delete browsing history on exit, and have tried increasing the disk space to use for temporary files with no avail as well.

The most confusing part of this is that the XAP file is the only file deleted, no other files are being wiped. I believe that this is something being done by a policy set up by IT, but they are not able to find the issue.

Do you have any recommendations as to what could be deleting the XAP file or a way I can catch the process which is deleting it?

Thanks,